# Use DataSet for retrieving, updating and inserting data to SQLite

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, dataset

**On visual studio I can create a DataSet of my SQLite database by doing:**

> 1) Connect to sqlite database file and create a table

[image]

> 2) Add new DataSet to my solution (DataSet2.xsd)

[image]

> 3) Drag tables to the designer

[image]

> ---

**Now how can I make use of the objects that visual studio created for me?**

for example I am trying to do something like:

```
        DataSet2.TableTestDataTable t = new DataSet2.TableTestDataTable();
        var objects = t.GetObjectData(..// do not know how to use it
```

OR

```
        DataSet2TableAdapters.TableTestTableAdapter t = new DataSet2TableAdapters.TableTestTableAdapter();
        var data = t.GetData(); 

        var q = from a in data
                select a;

        foreach (DataSet2.TableTestRow row in q)
        {
            row.integer = 12345; // change value of column integer               
        }
        t.submitchanges(); // method does note exists
```

Comment: can you use a DataReader instead DataReaders are much faster than DataSets and consume less memory.

Comment: Here is a link that will help you to get at what you are wanting to do better in my opinion http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10015984/getting-data-from-datatable.aspx

Comment: Yeah I can use Data reader. I want to avoid typing queries in a string. I prefer dealing with objects than with "Select * from..."  should I use regular sql commands instead and pass string queries?

Comment: Even better why not create a storedProc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    DataSet2TableAdapters.TableTestTableAdapter t = new DataSet2TableAdapters.TableTestTableAdapter();

    DataSet2 ds = new DataSet2();
    t.Fill(ds.TableTest); 

    foreach (DataSet2.TableTestRow row in ds.TableTest.Rows)
    {
        row.integer = 12345; // change value of column integer               
    }

    t.Update(ds2);
```

Something like that ....

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var q = (from a in data
        select a).ToArray();
```

And instead of `t.SubmitChanges();` use `t.Update(q);`.