# How to rewrite values in SQLite table using C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-4.5

For example, I have a table with two columns VariableName and Value. I need to edit a Value cell for some rows.
I use a code:

```
var stateVariable = from c in db.Table<StateVariables>() where c.VariableName == "cursor" select c;
stateVariable.First().Value = cursor;

stateVariable = from c in db.Table<StateVariables>() where c.VariableName == "cursor2" select c;
stateVariable.First().Value = cursor2;

stateVariable = from c in db.Table<StateVariables>() where c.VariableName == "isForward" select c;
stateVariable.First().Value = isForward;
```

This code not changes values in table. It seems I know the reason. Here I'm trying to edit extracted data, not db. So, how to edit a values directly in SQLite table?

Comment: It may be that the variable c is a copy not a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time, [LINQ's `SubmitChanges` worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477729/create-records-with-linq-to-sqlite-via-dblinq):

```
var recordToUpdate = (from c in db.xxx
                      where c.VariableName == "cursor"
                      select c).Single();
recordToUpdate.Value = cursor;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Nowadays, you [have to use `Update`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215492/use-dataset-for-retrieving-updating-and-inserting-data-to-sqlite) instead:

```
DataSet2TableAdapters.TableTestTableAdapter t = new DataSet2TableAdapters.TableTestTableAdapter();

DataSet2 ds = new DataSet2();
t.Fill(ds.TableTest); 

foreach (DataSet2.TableTestRow row in ds.TableTest.Rows)
{
    row.integer = 12345; // change value of column integer               
}

t.Update(ds2);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. SQLite.SQLiteConnection doesn't support SubmitChanges(). There is no such method in SQLite namespace.
Maybe, it's necessary to say that I'm making a Windows-Store app.

Comment: Finally, it works! In my case I need to use db.Update(stateVariable) each time after Value column is changed.